# MySQL database cannot accept SSL connections (Certs are UTD)

Tags: mysql, azure

Not sure if this is the right place for this kind of question, but I have a MySQL Database running on an Azure VM. Everything was working great, until last week it seemingly randomly stopped allowing SSL connections. From everything I've seen looking through the certificates on the VM and the ones assigned to the VM through the Azure portal, none of them are expired.

Even if I try to connect to the database while Remoting into the VM (so making it a local connection), it won't allow SSL. Not sure where to look from here, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Just wanted to add the fact that if I try to connect with No SSL it does connect fine. I just don't know why SSL stopped working all of the sudden. I also wasn't able to find any mention of the SSL cert in the config file, which seemed off to me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not with the database, but with the connector. As of v8.0.8 of the MySQL connector, they made it default to use SSL. If you want to not use SSL you just have to add "SslMode=none" to the end of your connection string.